# Need help outputting things from different functions (C++)

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to C++ and coding in general. I am trying to make just a basic little multiple choice type game for practice but I have run into a conundrum.

The program isn't outputting what I want it too. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void sword(int damage);
void fists(int damage);

static int enemyHealth = 250;

int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    string SOF; //Abreveation for "Sword Or Fists"

    cout << "You will be fighting a mean bad guy. Are you using a sword, or your fists?\n";

    while (SOF != "sword" && SOF != "fists"){
        cout << "Please enter your choice of either 'sword' or 'fists': ";
        cin >> SOF;
    }

    cout << "Okay! Time to fight! \n";

    if (SOF == "fists") {
        void fists();
    }
    else if (SOF == "sword") {
        void sword();
    }
    else{ (NULL); }

    cout << "Congratulations! You have vanquished that foul beast!\n";

    system("pause");
}

//This is for when the user chooses 'sword'
void sword(int damage = rand() % 100 + 50) {
    while (enemyHealth > 0){
        cout << "You deal " << damage << " damage with your sharp sword. \n";
        enemyHealth -= damage;
    }
}

//This is for when the user chooses 'fists'
void fists(int damage = rand() % 10 + 4) {
    while (enemyHealth > 0){
        cout << "You deal " << damage << " damage with your womanly fists. \n";
        enemyHealth -= damage;
    }
}
```

The first part works fine, but when I enter my choice of either `"fists"` or `"sword"` the output is:

```
Okay! Time to fight!
Congratulations! You have vanquished that foul beast!
```

But I want it to output the damage being done with either fists or sword.

If I could get some help with that, it would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, but now that I have corrected that error I am getting a different error: error C2660: 'fists' : function does not take 0 arguments I receive the same error for 'sword' as well. I apologize for my little knowledge of C++ thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void fists();` is a declaration, not a call, change to `fists();` and `sword();`

Other things to look at:

- Default parameters are declared in function declaration before `main` (or just move whole functions there)
- Default parameters in c++ are evaluated once, so all 'hits' will be the same in your code
- Local variable names are usually not named in uppercase, `SOF` looks loke it is a `#define`d constant or such.

Comment: Good answer. I would also suggest leaving out (NULL) in  else{ (NULL); }

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, but now that I have corrected that error I am getting a different error:                                                          error C2660: 'fists' : function does not take 0 arguments                  
I receive the same error for 'sword' as well. I apologize for my little knowledge of C++ thank you for the help.

Comment: @buddymcdoo that is because default parameters should be in declaration above `main` (also see other suggestions from answer)

Comment: Ahhhh I see. Thank you so much good sir. The program now runs beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

To call the function, don't write `void fists();`, just

```
fists();
```

(What you have is a declaration, which has no useful effect here, rather than a call.)